# Failed to exec start script

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

Angular: 5.0.1 /
Angular CLI: 1.5.0 /
Node: 8.9.1 /
npm: 5.5.1 /
Os: win32 x64

I get the below error when executing "npm start" in the terminal/command prompt. Can anyone help me resolve this? I have spent a whole day trying to fix it with no luck.

**Here is the scripts section of my package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080"
  },
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev.js');
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json') }
          } , 'angular2-template-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
      helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      htmlLoader: {
        minimize: false // workaround for ng2
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

**Here is the error**

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe', 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js', 1 verbose cli
>   'start' ] 2 info using npm@5.5.1 3 info using node@v8.9.1 4 verbose
>   run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ] 5 info lifecycle
>   angular-io-example@1.0.0~prestart: angular-io-example@1.0.0 6 info
>   lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~start: angular-io-example@1.0.0 7
>   verbose lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in
>   lifecycle true 8 verbose lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~start:
>   PATH: C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\cbonsu\Downloads\sample_pro\webpack\node_modules.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
>   SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\cbonsu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
>   Code\bin;C:\Users\cbonsu\AppData\Roaming\npm 9 verbose lifecycle
>   angular-io-example@1.0.0~start: CWD:
>   C:\Users\cbonsu\Downloads\sample_pro\webpack 10 silly lifecycle
>   angular-io-example@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 10 silly lifecycle
>   'webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080' ] 11 silly
>   lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal:
>   null 12 info lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec
>   start script 13 verbose stack Error: angular-io-example@1.0.0 start:
>   `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080` 13 verbose stack
>   Exit status 1 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.
>   (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
>   13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) 13 verbose stack
>   at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7) 13 verbose stack     at
>   ChildProcess. (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
>   13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) 13 verbose stack
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) 13 verbose stack     at
>   maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16) 13 verbose stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
>   14 verbose pkgid angular-io-example@1.0.0 15 verbose cwd
>   C:\Users\cbonsu\Downloads\sample_pro\webpack 16 verbose Windows_NT
>   10.0.15063 17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "start" 18 verbose node v8.9.1 19 verbose npm  v5.5.1 20 error code
>   ELIFECYCLE 21 error errno 1 22 error angular-io-example@1.0.0 start:
>   `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080` 22 error Exit
>   status 1 23 error Failed at the angular-io-example@1.0.0 start script.
>   23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above. 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: can you share your `webpack.config.js` file

Comment: I have now shared it together with webpack.common.js, webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js

Answer (score 14):

it should make it

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install

npm start
```

Comment: npm clean cache does not work. It returns the available npm usage commands.

Comment: npm cache clean returns this "As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead". I tried "npm cache verify" as stated in the message followed by "npm start" however the problem still persists.

Comment: try: npm cache clean --force

Comment: No, I didn't delete node_modules first.... I have now deleted node_modules and re-run the commands "npm clean cache --force", "npm install", and finally "npm start". The problem still persists.

Comment: this actually works, i had a similar problem in react native and this worked thanks

Answer (score 2):

I simply got this issue resolved by verifying and cleaning cache, then updating npm to latest version.

```
npm cache verify
npm install
npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

If `npm clean cache --force` `npm install` `npm start` didn't work for you. Try rename the root folder. It's stragnely work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered an easier approach to this. Discard the "npm start" and webpack approach altogether and use angular-cli. With angular-cli, calling "ng build --prod" handles everything (aot etc). Behind the scene it uses webpack but it handles all the complications involved so developers don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack-dev-server" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.